# Show these two polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Need to show both of these are irreducible:

$f(t) = t^4 -14t^2 + 44 = 0 $

and $g(t) = t^4 -24t^2 + 4= 0$. I've tried Eisensteins but can't get anywhere.

Comment: Let $x=t^2$ maybe?

Comment: @AJStas I've tried, but if I new polynomial in x is irreducible then does that mean $f$ is?

Comment: @AJStas Incorrect. Consider for instance $(x^2-2)^2$ which is reducible.

Comment: If all else fails, you can just compute the zeros $a_j\notin\mathbb Q$ and check that these don't have minimal polynomials of degree $2$.

Comment: @GitGud Fair enough.

Comment: The first one is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_3$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Suppose it was reducible. Show that your polynomial has no real root, and then show f cannot be a product of two quadratics. Suppose it was and show that this leads to a contradiction

Comment: Once you have checked there are no rational roots, you can look for a factorization as a product of monic quadratics. Since there is no $x^3$ term,     the coefficients of $x$ must be the negatives of each other. But then since there is no $x$ term, the constants must be equal. Now it's almost over.

Comment: The reality is that the Eisenstein criterion almost never works on a randomly chosen irreducible polynomial of degree greater than 2. You usually have to rig examples to make them Eisenstein.  Your default test should be reduction mod $p$ for some $p$, but that too can fail, especially for irreducible quartics of the form $x^4 + ax^2 + b$.

Comment: To expand a bit on @KCd’s comment: Eisenstein will work only if some prime is totally ramified in the extension gotten by adjoining a single root; Irreducibility over $\Bbb F_p$ will work only if $p$ is inert in that extension. Even this happens less often than you’d like, when the degree is bigger than two.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t)$ is reducible, it factors as $f(t)=h(t)y(t)$. There are two possibilities: 1.) $h(t)$ has degree one and $y(t)$ has degree three or 2.) $h(t)$ and $y(t)$ have degree two.

Case 1.: $h$ has degree one if and only if $f(t)$ has a root $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$. by rational root theorem, the only possible rational roots are $\alpha=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p|44$ and $q|1$ i.e. plus or minus$\{1,2,4,11,44\}$. None of these should be a root of $f$, so case 1 can't happen

Case 2.: $h(t)y(t)=(at^2+bt+c)(\alpha t^2+\beta t+\gamma)=f(t)=t^4-14t^2+44$. Now foil and you'll solve a system of equations. You'll get a contradiction because of the restriction $a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{Q}$. So case 2 can't happen.

Thus, $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Same thing should work for $g$

Comment: $p | 44 \implies p=\pm(1,2,4,11,44)$ , not just $\pm44$.

Comment: Right my mistake, I'll fix it. I didn't check, but none should work

Comment: Gauss' theorem on content shows that you can take the coefficients actual integers, not just rational, in case (2). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29 Becomes quick, because you can take $\alpha = a = 1,$ then calculate $\beta = -b,$ finally $\gamma = c$ which fails because $44$ is not a square

Answer (score 1):

Let's try $f(t)$. 
$f(t)$ is of degree $4$ so it has at most $4$ roots. What are the possibilities? Either it has at least one linear factor, or it has no linear factors - two irreducible quadratic factors. These questions always go the same way.

You can use the rational root test to see if it has a linear factor.

Then if not, you have to rule out two quadratic factors. So, suppose it factored into two irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$. Well, by Gauss' lemma, you only need to see if it factors over $\mathbb{Z}$, so just imagine the polynomials are instead in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, equate coefficients and do some algebra and try to come up with a contradiction. Usually, it'll be that one of the coefficients which you assumed was an integer will not be an integer. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: first, in each case, divide the roots by $2$, to get the easier-to-handle polynomials $t^4-7t^2+11$ and $t^4-12t^2+1$.

For the first of these, $t^4-7t^2+11\equiv t^4-t^2-1\pmod3$. Has no roots modulo $3$, and since the only irreducible quadratic polynomials over $\Bbb F_3$ are $t^2+1$, $t^2+t-1$, and $t^2-t-1$, and none of these divides our quartic, it’s irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$, and thus over $\Bbb Z$, and thus over $\Bbb Q$. (Thanks to @GitGud.)

For the second polynomial, $g(t)=t^4-12t^2+1$, and if $\alpha$ is a root, then $\alpha^2$ is a root of $t^2-12t+1$, thus $\alpha^2=6\pm\sqrt{35}$. Now let’s use the arithmetic of real quadratic fields, in particular the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{35}\,)$. An integral basis is $\{1,\sqrt{35}\}$, and by standard methods involving continued fractions, you know that $6+\sqrt35$ is a fundamental unit. In particular, its square root is not in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{35}\,)$, so that $\bigl[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q\bigr]=4$, and thus the polynomial $t^4-12t^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, and consequently irreducible.

Comment: You don't need continued fractions or fundamental units to know $6+\sqrt{35}$ is not a square in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{35}]$: the square of any element of $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{35}]$ has an even coefficient of $\sqrt{35}$.

Comment: Shows the disadvantage, @KCd, of looking for a fancy explanation first!